# How do I install my forked React modules into Symfony 4?

Tags: reactjs, module, symfony4

I'm trying install a React module into my Symfony 4 project. I already have the React entry point setup and running with webpack encore, and now I want to add a module to the React app.

The React module has a github and can be installed through npm, but how do I install it into Symfony? How do I deal with the `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` files in the package, since Symfony has its own for these files.

I have compared the `webpack.config.js` and it seems like the Symfony one can override the other one, since it already covers React entry point and babel setup. What do I do?

Another problem I have is that the original module was outdated, so I forked the project to my repository, updated it and filed a pull request. But since the PR is still pending, I wanted to install my fork for now, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

NPM supports installing dependencies directly from github (or other git host) https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install so executing `npm install github:<githubname>/<githubrepo>[#<commit-ish>]` should work fine from the package.json directory.

> The React module has a github and can be installed through npm, but how do I install it into Symfony? How do I deal with the webpack.config.js and package.json files in the package, since Symfony has its own for these files.

I'm not familiar with Symfony, does it manage your NPM dependencies after install? If so you will have to determine how to accomplish the `npm install` via Symfony.

> Another problem I have is that the original module was outdated, so I forked the project to my repository, updated it and filed a pull request. But since the PR is still pending, I wanted to install my fork for now, what do I need to do?

As per above, just specify your git path until your PR is pulled, then update package.json to the original repo